# increase performance of mysql rows vs users

Tags: mysql, database, performance

I have a server with 128MB ram.I have enabled user registration.The users that register generate data and store them.The data they generate is huge eg clicks ,profile info,referrer urls,unique id,states etc, Is it wise for me to create a table for each user and store them individually will that increase query performance? or should I group all users in one giant table with several rows? The difference would be while selecting  `username123.fileid where id = 2` vs `veryongtable.username123 where fileid = ""`

Comment: 128MB RAM vs _huge_ data is not going to end well, no matter what you do... (given that you're not just writing the tables) Also one table per user is a _major_ smell...

Comment: Agree with ppeterka. 128MB is a joke. Also this `veryongtable.username123` doesn't do what you think :) What you wrote there is `databasename.tablename`. It'd be `verylongtable where fileid = "" and username = 'username123'`

Comment: ELectricity to run a machine with that little ram costs more than getting a raspberry with 512mb. Unless you plan to use the 486 as a space heater. you can find free hosting with more ram than that..

Answer (score 2):

I think its better to keep the users in one table and if your query runs slowly, add an index for the relevant columns.

You have to be careful though, to not run out of memory with only 128mb ...